# Authentication Logic - Server vs Client

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get my head around where authentication logic should live in my application, the approach I am trying to take is to have any auth responsibility handled by the server, redirecting to a login page that's separate from the main client side app - which I think is sensible?

I have an angularjs application which uses ui-router and makes api requests which are routed via the server.

I am using an Express server which is configured to use a couple of directories like so:

```
app.use(express.static('./dist/client'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I then have middleware that performs an auth check (Im using express-session as well) and redirecting to login when required.

```
//A request to '/login' will serve the login page
app.use('/login', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/login.html'))
});

//This will listen for all requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url!== '/auth/login' && !req.session.accessToken) {
    res.redirect('/login');
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```

On initial page load, when no session cookie exists, express immediately redirects to the login view as expected.

After logon, and the main application loads, if I then manually delete the cookie in the browser and perform a state change that requires an api request (in a state resolve), the server returns the login view but this gets rendered inside the `ui-view` component being used by ui-router, rather than a full redirect to `/login` by the server.

Also, if I navigate to a page (after deleting cookie) that does not perform an api request, that page is served back, I guess as its not covered by my `app.use` middleware that does the redirect.

I feel I'm missing something obvious here, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this, there are others:

Make the API server return a 401 (unauthorized) error if the user is not authenticated, rather than redirecting them to the login page.

Then, in a run block, add a `$stateChangeError` event handler to the `$rootScope`. This way, if an API request is made from an unauthenticated user, it will trigger the event handler. From there you can redirect the user to your login page:

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function($rootScope, $window) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function() {
    $window.location.href = '/login';
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if it makes sense to worry about the other scenario where you delete the cookie and navigate to a page that does not make any API requests. What is such a user going to gain? In this hypothetical scenario, they are already looking at a page in your app (that might have sensitive data or not). How did they get there to begin with?

You could use a similar event handler for the `$stateChangeStart` event that checks for the presence of the cookie and redirect if it's missing. But, you don't want to put code in your client that validates the cookie, b/c then any curious visitor could read that code and learn how to create a cookie to fool your server.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil, I have tried this and am now returning 401's back from server, which I see in the browser console, but the $stateChangeError is not firing for me. I can however catch the error in a httpResponseInterceptor. Any ideas why the 401 is not being picked up by the $stateChangeError?

Comment: I am also using resolves on my routes, and its these that are throwing the 401 from my express app, so I would have though these would cause the stateChangeError handler to fire?

Comment: @mindparse I use the same technique w/resolves and the $stateChangeError handler, so I can confirm that it should work. I'm not sure what could be wrong. I think the HTTP interceptor approach is fine too.